# Can Send_File be invoked without "Return Send_file"?

Tags: python

I am attempting to upload a CSV file, process it, create a new CSV response file and send it back (download to browser). I have this almost working, the end part of the code is:-

```
        flash('Statement Processed, please check returned file for status','success')
        path = 'static/' + name + '.csv'
        f.close()
        # return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

        return redirect(url_for('main.treasurer'))
```

This code does everything I need except the download (send_file commented out)

```
        flash('Statement Processed, please check returned file for status','success')
        path = 'static/' + name + '.csv'
        f.close()
        return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

        return redirect(url_for('main.treasurer'))
```

This code does the download but does not return me to the main.treasurer screen and does not display the flashed message.

My question therefore is can I execute the send_file function without using it within a "Return" statement? If I can't then I guess I'll just need to add a back button to the current screen.

Comment: `send_file` is a function. by executing that in a return statement you are returning whatever is returned by the `send_file` function. I don't see any reason why that needs to be in the return statement.

Comment: You can try adding a link to just download the file into  the above response and have the user click on it, this will prompt them to download the file and they'll remain on that page. The download link will point to e.g `return send_file('/some/file/sample.py', as_attachment=True)`

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions;  user1558604; I should have said that I had tried running the command without the Return but it didn't work, something within the function I guess.   Thanks Gideon Maina, I have implemented what you suggest; although it's not my preferred approach but it works fine and I'll stick with it..